# What is a good way to regenerate HTML table on jQuery event, instead of appending to div element?

Tags: jquery, html-table

My plan was to use jQuery's `.data()` method to store my table row information in a hidden `div` element.

Then, upon clicking an `Add` or `Remove` row button, I would modify the jQuery `data` in the hidden `div`, clear the table `div` contents, and then regenerate the table's rows from the data stored in the hidden `div`.

To start with, my project handles at most five or six rows, four columns. Not much data, but I'm not too experienced with jQuery, so my question is whether this is the ideal way to go about this, or if there are gotchas in doing this before I start writing code. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just store the data in memory in JavaScript and then do a replaceWith() the new HTML?

Comment: If I keep it in memory, will the data be accessible to jQuery routines called in other .js files?

Comment: Yes, it will.  As long as it's in the global scope.